# Sending Concurrent Requests to SAP endpoint is Timed out from Strapi endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, .net-6.0, sap

I have Function in C# Which posts a certain ledger in a JSON format to a `SAP` endpoint. I have 12 such JSON that needs to be posted. But as it happens 11/12 JSON post successfully, but the last one gets `timed out`. From my side I have increased the `Max timeout limit to 5 minutes`
The timed-out response says

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time  or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (interfaces.confidential.com:443).

Also the timeout response returns `200 status code even after timing out`.

I also have a retry policy in place if the response is not 200.

```
public async Task<string> InvokePostAsync(string jsonString,string clientId, string fileName)
 {
     string result = null;
     HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
     string submissionTime = null;
     string responseTime = null;

     try
     {
         if (jsonString.IsNotNullEmptyOrWhitespace()) {
             var client = new HttpClient();
             client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); // max timeout limit set to 5 minutes

             var retryPolicy = Policy
                 .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                 .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
             submissionTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(); //retry after 3 sec if not 200 status 
             response = await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
             {
                 var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri( _appSettings.postEndpoint) );
                 request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
                 request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {_appSettings.AuthToken}");
                 request.Content = new StringContent(jsonString);

                 return await client.SendAsync(request);
             });
             responseTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
             response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
             result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

             _logger.LogInformation($"Post result for client {clientId}:" + result);
         }
         
         return await createEmailMessageforClient(true,clientId,submissionTime,responseTime,fileName,result,(int)response.StatusCode);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         responseTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(); 
         _logger.LogError($"Error while posting web service for client: {clientId} Exception: {ex.Message}");
         return await createEmailMessageforClient(false, clientId, submissionTime, responseTime, fileName, ex.Message, (int)response.StatusCode);
     }
 }
```

I feel like from my side I have done Everything fine, And I think The SAP endpoint has a rate limit set to it. Please let me know if I can tackle this issue from my code itself. OR is it only configurable using the SAP interface?

Comment: SAP is a very big company with many software, databases, languages, and is 1/3 the size of Microsoft. You'll need to tell more about the "SAP endpoint" otherwise it's impossible to say anything concerning this part of the question...

Comment: @SandraRossi The issue in my case is that The clients are not co-operating as to what are their configuration for this particular endpoint. I was wondering if there were like a `default Rate limit or Firewalls` set up by SAP. That blocks certain IP addresses from interacting with them?

Comment: My current Post request is for the endpoint which accepts a General ledger in Serialized format.

Comment: Again, which one of the SAP software is it? Give as much information as you can. Note that these technical limits may not be part of the SAP software itself.

Comment: Your approach is correct I've faced this issue before too, Turns out it's the rate limit that was blocking the request. Also check if your firewall is causing the timeout issue